# Getting java rmi exception in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have checked all setting on master and slave. All seems correct. When I start from host in jmeter. Getting following error :

[image]

Not sure if it is problem of ultimate thread group plugin or master/slave setting. If I do start from host with default jmeter test plan then it works fine.

I have not installed ultimate thread group on server. Should I install on server as well?

Comment: You need to install plugins on the slave machine, too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you must install all plugins that are on jmeter controller on the jmeter server.

As you can see in error, there is a ClassNotFoundException happening.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimate thread group plugin is missing on the JMeter-server.

You should install all the plugins in the server machines which are already on your master machines.

Comment: I was thinking same but I have only SSH access to server, How can I install plugins via command line?

Comment: Try to taper off using bold-face please. It doesn't help.

Comment: Put your plugins jar in the "lib/ext" directory. That's all.